# sql (create view) statement with two ids from a table to an other table

Tags: sql, select, inner-join, sql-view

I'am a sql newbie.
I have two data base tables:

```
T_VALUE
valueId
value
valueInfo

T_SAMPLE
sampleId
valueId
oldValueId
sampleInfo
```

The valueId and the oldValueId of table T_SAMPLE are the valueId of table T_VALUE.

I am looking for a select (create view) statement for the following output:

```
V_DIFF
sampleId
sampleInfo
valueInfo (from T_VALUE record determined by valueId)
value (from T_VALUE record determined by valueId)
diffValue (=value from V_DIFF minus the value from T_VALUE record determined by oldValueId)
```

**Further problems:** The record for oldValueId can not exist **or** the oldValueId of T_SAMPLE can be null **or** the value of the record determined by oldValueId of T_VALUE can be null. Then the Output of diffValue should be the value (from T_VALUE record determined by valueId).

Thank you for your hints Lykke

Answer (score 1):

I think you want two joins:

```
create view v_diff as
select s.sampleid, s.sampleinfo, v1.valueinfo, v1.value,
    v1.value - v2.value as diffvalue
from t_sample s
inner join t_value v1 on v1.valueid = s.valueid
inner join t_value v2 on v2.valueid = s.oldvalueid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create view v_diff as
select distinct s.sampleid, s.sampleinfo, v1.valueinfo, v1.value,
    v1.value - coalesce(v2.value, 0) as diffvalue
from t_sample s
inner join t_value v1 on v1.valueid = s.valueid
left join t_value v2 on v2.valueid = s.oldvalueid
```

should solve my **further problems**, or?